# TypeError: In this environment the sources for assign MUST be an object. This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant

Tags: react-native

Getting this error in expo / react-native project. What I am trying to do is use react-native-elements and create a button with some text and an Icon off to the right. My Render function looks like

```
return (
<View>
 <Header /> 
  <Button icon={
   <Icon 
     type="entypo"
     name="plus" />
   }
   iconRight
   title="Add City" 
  />
</View>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using react-native-elements v0.19.0. This error happens because in that RNE version the iconRight prop should be an object instead of boolean. This was changed in the latest RNE version, which now uses a boolean.
So, you can update yor RNE version (yarn add react-native-elements@beta) or update your code to match v0.19.0 (iconRight={{name: 'code'}})